# How to extract the entire four dimension array in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

```
import os
import numpy as np

filename = 'gfs_air201504.npz'
data = np.load('data/'+ filename)
a2 = data['gfs_air']
print(type(a2))
print(a2.shape)

print(a2[131,227,238,:])

print(a2[0,0,0,:])
```

How to extract all data from the fourth dimension and save into CSV file. The last dimension contains 13 features.

Comment: Okay, and what am I supposed to do with your code? Where is your data? A [mcve]?

Comment: be more specific, show us some data

Comment: How to share the data?. The data we have downloaded from the http://airnet.caiyunapp.com/

Comment: `a2[0,0,0,:]` gives all '4th dimension' values at one point (as defined by the first 3 indices).  `a2[:,:,:,0]` is a 3d arrays with the 0th index on the 4th dimension.  `a2` is the whole 4 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not pretty clear but you can give this a shot:

```
arr[0][0][0][0:]  #all the items in fourth dimension for a specific index
```

Comment: I want to extract all the data in the fourth dimension (all indexes).

Comment: In `numpy` we prefer to index multiple dimensions with `arr[0,0,0,:]`, one indexing expression rather than multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take all information from the first 3 dimensions. You can do that by using ':' for the first 3 dimension slots in the array. In the 4th slot where you call the 4th dimension you need to specify which index of the 4th dimension you are calling. 0 would call your first index, 1 would call the second etc...

```
# print all info from 4th dimension at index 0
print(arr[:,:,:,0])
```